# time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

An algorith with size n=100 takes 21 seconds to run. With size n=1000 it takes 31 seconds and with n=10000 takes 41 seconds to run. What is the running complexity?

If I try O(n) Then: T(n)=(21*1000)/100 = 210 s (Not  O(n))
If I try O(n^2) Then: T(n)=(21*1000^2)/100^2 = 2100 s (Not  O(n^2))
If I try O(log n) then: T(n)=(21*log1000)/log100=31.5 (Not O(log n))

The other option I am given is O(1/n). How do I calculate this?

Comment: *More* Big O homework Maria/Annita ?

Comment: yes as u can see I tried to solve it but cannot find how to calculate O(1/n). Can u help please?

Comment: May be helpful: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=94000

Comment: Bogus Question. We cannot determine just from a sample of 3 values.

Answer (score 6):

looks like an `O(lgn)`.

The time for `n` is `T(n) = 10*log(n) + 1` when the base of the log is 10.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem start by plotting some functions from the various classes. For example to learn about the `O(n)` linear class plot the function `T(n)=n` and to learn about the `O(n^2)` class plot the function `T(n)=n^2`. This will help you recognize the shape of the various functions.

After that, plot the points given in your questions with the values of n in the x-axis and the timed values on the y-axis. You should be able to quickly recognize the shape in this question.

Hint: It's not `O(log n)`  :-)

Comment: do u think is O(n)? The graph is linear. But when I use the formula  I get: T(n)=(21*1000)/100 = 210 s not 31s.

Comment: @Maria Yes I think it is. With only timing data you can never be sure, but it's the best guess we have. Remembering that constants "dont count" when using the big O notation and that a linear euqation can have the form "y = kx + m", ie there can be a "starting-cost" for the algorithm bounded by a constant. Your calculations assume T(0) = 0 which is not always true. You see? Check the plot again. The line does not cut the y-axis at the origo.